# How can i use OnChange affecting a dropDown but without taking a default value

Tags: angular

I have two values Company and Employees,

When I change the company, the dropDown of employees takes a default value(the first employee of the list).

How can I use OnChange without letting Employee DropDown takes a default and just takes the value 'all' non selectable.

This is my code :
ts:

```
 objChangeCompany(cmp) {
  this.employeService.GetAllEmployeeByCompany(cmp)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.empList = data;
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

html:

```
 <div class="form-group societe">
        <label class="control-label">{{'Company' | translate}}</label>
        <select class="form-control" formControlName="Company" (change)="objChangeCompany($event.target.value)"
          required="true">
          <option *ngFor="let i of cmpList" [value]="i.id">{{i.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group societe">
        <label class="control-label">{{'Employee' | translate}}</label>
        <select class="form-control" formControlName="Employee"
          (change)="objChangeEmp($event.target.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let a of empList" [value]="a.id">{{a.nom}} {{a.prenom}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any help and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a option with value null and give the value null to the control

```
   <select class="form-control" formControlName="Employee"
      (change)="objChangeEmp($event.target.value)">
      <!--add this option-->
      <option [ngValue]="null" disabled hidden>Select one</option>
      <!--the rest of options-->
      <option *ngFor="let a of empList" [value]="a.id">{{a.nom}} {{a.prenom}}</option>
    </select>
```

NOTE: In angular it's common subscribe to [valueChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) instead of use (change) event